# Does progurad obfuscate tableview in javafx

Tags: javafx, obfuscation, proguard

I have created a JavaFX application, it have TableView to show table data. I am obfuscating final jar using Proguard-4.8, but unable to view data in TableView, we have created public static classes for table data binding. In my table if I have three columns say two columns show text and remaining one column have button added then after obfuscation I am able to see button only, rest two columns show blank rows.

[image]

Without obfuscation my jar showing all text data correctly. I have no CSS applied over TableView.

Can someone suggest me where I am doing wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Are you using PropertyValueFactory? This would mean the property is accessed via reflection and if you obfuscate the property it can't be found anymore!

Comment: Thanks, Yes we are using PropertyValueFactory, how can I skip those from obfuscation as my proguard.map showing for one object as  javafx.beans.property.StringProperty myObject -> i